# Why Error code 115 is coming when doing check out in ccavenue test environment?

Tags: ccavenue

I am integrating ccavenue payment gateway and downloaded nodejs environment ,when i run it and open datafrom.html and do checkout i am getting error code 115

Comment: please spend few minutes reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: I know it is very late but still, did you get success to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact the CCAvenue support(Call: 02267425555. Dial 0 for operator. Ask for "Technical Support" section) for this.

I had this issue and I was trying to do the payment integration on my custom application. The problem was that I was redirecting to the test server of CCAvenue (sandbox mode). And they haven't configured their server to accept my test transactions.

So at first there was "10002 Authentication Failed" error. Because the url(test url in my server) from which I was initiated the transaction, was not whitelisted in the CCAvenue server. So, like in my case, if you have two different urls (or two domains/subdomains), one for the testing and the other as production, then you would have to send the mail to them requesting to whitelist your test url.

And you would be asked to send an email for this purpose, to this email id: `service@ccavenue.com`

For each URL you have (test and production), they will generate different set of `access_code` and `working_key` values. Make sure you login to your Merchant Dashboard and visit Settings menu --> API Keys for these values.

[image]